# How to continue a lap count

Tags: r, loops, count, lag

I have a simple question, that I unfortunately cannot seem to get right (being very new to R).
I have a variable that represents a lap count. After some time the lapcount was reset, though I want to have it continue counting.

From what I've researched I probably need a loop to do this, but I cannot seem to get one to work.

Could anybody be so kind as to help me out?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Here is an example dataset and the expected outcome:

```
dataset <- data.frame(lap = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2))

expected outcome<-data.frame(lap = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,9))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rle`, which counts the times of each repeated numbers, and then reconstruct the value using `rep`.

```
lap <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
rle_lap <- rle(lap)
expected <- data.frame(lap = rep(1:length(rle_lap$lengths), rle_lap$lengths))
```

Comment: Thanks that works great! So nice to have this help; did not know of this function, so would also never have thought of looking for this!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with `dplyr`:

```
 library(dplyr)
 dataset %>% mutate(expected = cumsum(lap != dplyr::lag(lap, 1, default = 0)))
```